# Setting up config file in terminal

Tags: config

I'm setting up Solana on an M1 mac and I've reached a hurdle.

I'm meant to set up a file at `~/.cargo/config` and include the instructions featured in the attached photo.

How do I set up the file though?

Comment: you forgot to attach the screenshot.  but please don't attach screenshots of text!  use code blocks instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use any text editor. If all else fails, just use TextEdit.app that comes with macOS.

In the Terminal, you could type

```
open -a TextEdit ~/.cargo/config
```

Then, a TextEdit window will open and you can edit the file. Just close and save when you're done, and resume your work on the Terminal.